# Angular Data-Binding from Service to Component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, promise, observable

I want to display a loading indicator whenever an Http Request sent. 
I try to use Angular [Http Interceptor](https://angular.io/guide/http#logging) but style of indicator is never updates.

I have a [loading indicator](https://material.angular.io/components/progress-bar/overview#indeterminate) in my app.component.html

```
  <div [style.display]="visibilityOfLoadingIndicator">
    <mat-progress-bar mode="indeterminate" color="warn" ></mat-progress-bar>
  </div>
```

Here is the app.component.ts:

```
export class AppComponent {


  visibilityOfLoadingIndicator = 'none';

  constructor(public loadingIndicatorService: LoadingIndicatorService) {
    this.loadingIndicatorService.getLoadingIndicator()
    .subscribe(visibility => {
      this.visibilityOfLoadingIndicator = <string> visibility;
    });

    }
  }
```

Here is the HttpLoadingIndicatorService.ts:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoadingIndicatorService implements HttpInterceptor {


  private display;

  private loadingIndicator: EventEmitter<string>;

  constructor() {
  this.loadingIndicator = new  EventEmitter<string>();
  }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const started = Date.now();
    console.log('Request started');
    this.display = 'block';
    this.updateVisibility(this.display);
    return next.handle(req)
      .pipe(
        finalize(
          () => {
            const elapsed = Date.now() - started;
            const msg = `${req.method} "${req.urlWithParams}"
            in ${elapsed} ms.`;
            console.log(msg);
            this.display = 'none';
            this.updateVisibility(this.display);
          }
        )
      )
      ;
  }



  updateVisibility(state: string) {
    this.loadingIndicator.emit(state);
  }

  getLoadingIndicator() {
    return this.loadingIndicator;
  }


}
```

My service is working for example this is the console output:

```
->Request started

->http-loading-indicator.service.ts:24 GET "http://localhost:8080/api/film"
            in 2164 ms.
```

But why style of indicator is not updating?

Should I create [Observable](https://angular.io/guide/observables)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to have the component subscribe to changes from the service so it can tell Angular that things have changed.

```
  constructor(public  authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
              public loadingIndicatorService: HttpLoadingIndicatorService,
              changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef) {
      loadingIndicatorService.displayChangeObservable.subscribe(() =>
      { 
          changeDetector.markForCheck();
      });
  }

  displayLoadingIndicator() {
    return this.loadingIndicatorService.display;
  }

}
```

Service

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HttpLoadingIndicatorService implements HttpInterceptor {

  private displayChangeSubject = new Subject<any>();
  public displayChangeObservable = this.displayChangeSubject.asObservable();

  display = 'none';

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const started = Date.now();
    console.log('Request started');
    this.display = 'block';
    this.displayChangeSubject.next();
    return next.handle(req)
      .pipe(
        finalize(
          () => {
            const elapsed = Date.now() - started;
            const msg = `${req.method} "${req.urlWithParams}"
            in ${elapsed} ms.`;
            console.log(msg);
            this.display = 'none';
            this.displayChangeSubject.next();
          }
        )
      )
      ;
  }

}
```

Comment: Sorry for late feedback, I have tried your code today but it is not updating the visibility. I can update question with new code.